# Displaying an HTML popup using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make an HTML page that displays another html file in an alert; but it's not displaying when the triggering button is pressed.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        function pop() {
            xmlhttp.open("GET","content.html",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if(xmlhttp.readystate==4&&xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" name="test" value="push" onclick="pop()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the content of content.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hi!
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to use jQuery. Saves you some work and your code will be much nicer to read. http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: This sounds remarkably like homework to me.

Comment: How can i obtian Hi! only instead of the whole html code???thanks

Comment: Yup i would like to learning ajax and i  am finding some ajax exercise online.

Comment: We appreciate it when homework is actually tagged as homework. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it's `readyState`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Also, it might be better to send after setting up everything.

Lastly, you have a missing `}`.

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

function pop()
{
 xmlhttp.open("GET","content.html",true);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 { if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200)
    {alert(xmlhttp.responseText);}
 }
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: alright. Thanks everyone. It seems I made some careless mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, i'm counting three opening braces (`{`) but only two closing braces (`}`). Check your browser's error console to spot such errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check Below: Closing bracket is missing.

var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

```
function pop()
{
   xmlhttp.open("GET","content.html",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {

if(xmlhttp.readystate==4&&xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
   }
  }
}
```