# AJAX Beginner with DOMException issue

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am following along with a tutorial book on AJAX and I seem to be failing on some basic concept.

**Here is the HTML and Javascript I am using** (this is saved as ajax.html on my godaddy hosted web server):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AJAX Example</title>
        <script language="javascript">
            var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            function getData(dataSource, divID) {
                if (XMLHttpRequestObject) {
                    var obj = document.getElementById(divID);
                    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource);

                    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readystate == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
                            obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                        }
                    }                   
                    XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
                }
            }        
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <H1>This is an AJAX Example</H1>

        <form>
            <input type="button" value="Fetch the Message" onclick="getData('data.txt', 'targetDiv')">
        </form>
        <div id="targetDiv">
            <p>The fetched message is supposed to appear here...</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And is the contents of data.txt** (saved in the same directory as ajax.html):

```
<p>This is some text in a file that I am using to be</p> 
<p>queried with an ajax process to display dynamically.</p>
```

The problem is that nothing happens when I press the button on the page. I have tried to step through the Javascript using Chrome's developer tools and I see a `DOMException`:
[image].

Can someone please point out if there is an issue with this javascript, or point me in the right direction to deal with the `DOMException` that I am  seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730923/beginner-of-ajax-stuck-with-grabbing-content) I read that my `readystate` should really be `readyState`. Changing that fixed my problem.

Comment: Check off that you've answered the question